# Firebase checking value if its null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

im working on a simple coding here but i kind of stuck.

basicly the code will check if the username exists or not, so im using these codes;

Data Structure;

```
"usernametouid": {
        "username": "userid",
}
```

Codes;

```
 this.afDatabase.object(`usernametouid/${this.username}`).subscribe(data => { 

      const dtvl = data.$value;


      if(dtvl != null) {

    console.log("username exists")

      } else if(dtvl == null) {

        console.log("good to go")

        this.createProfile();

      }
```

on createProfile function that gets a uid so value being no longer null.

Actually its working allright if username already exist part, but if its not, for a little moment (i assume during retrieving data ) it getting not-null again.

So output being like this (if type a null username):

```
good to go
username exists
```

i dont understand why its giving me "username exists" again ? what would be the solution or any better way.

thanks for your assist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `angularfire2` library.
The `this.afDatabase.object('<objectAddress>')` returns a `FirebaseObjectObservable` (which is deprecated btw). This `Observable` will emit values whenever something changes inside that object.

In your case everything works quite logically.

1. You subscribe to the `FirebaseObjectObservable`
2. The observable emits current value of that object in the database
3. At first the value is `null`, so you get the output of 'good to go'
4. You call `this.createProfile();` which I guess now creates the profile and changes the object you subscribed to in the database. Setting its `"username"` to the newly created `id`.
5. Since the object was changed in the database, the `FirebaseObjectObservable` emits new value. And your subscription function runs again. This time `data.$value` is not `null` as it now contains the newly created id.

If you just want to get the current value of the object once, you could make use of `.take(1)` RxJS operator. Or `.pipe(take(1))` depending on the RxJS version. This makes sure the observable emits only once.

Comment: thanks for your well support. I am very happy hence you understood me completely right. but i dont really know where to put that take(1). actually im using it at authstate like this: this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth =>..... but when trying at afdatabase it says take is not available in FirebaseDatabase

Comment: i found by brute-force :) right before ".subscribe" . thanks again for your support, appreciated!